# Parse string into a tree structure?

Tags: parsing, clojure, tree, text-processing, text-parsing

I'm trying to figure out how to parse a string in this format into a tree like data structure of arbitrary depth.

```
"{{Hello big|Hi|Hey} {world|earth}|{Goodbye|farewell} {planet|rock|globe{.|!}}}"

[[["Hello big" "Hi" "Hey"]
  ["world" "earth"]]
 [["Goodbye" "farewell"]
  ["planet" "rock" "globe" ["."
                            "!"]]]]
```

I've tried playing with some regular expressions for this (such as #"{([^{}]*)}" ), but everything I've tried seems to "flatten" the tree into a big list of lists.  I could be approaching this from the wrong angle, or maybe a regex just isn't the right tool for the job.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10):

Don't use regular expressions for this task. An easier method would be to describe your string with a grammar (BNF or EBNF) and then write a parser to parse the string according to the grammar. You can generate a parse-tree from your EBNF and BNF and so you naturally end up with a tree structure.

You can start with something like this:

```
element      ::= element-type, { ["|"], element-type }
element-type ::= primitive | "{", element, "}"
primitive    ::= symbol | word
symbol       ::= "." | "!"
word         ::= character { character }
character    ::= "a" | "b" | ... | "z"
```

Note: I wrote this up quickly, and so it may not be completely correct. But it should give you an idea.

Comment: So after having that grammar, it is necessary to use a parser generator to generate parser based on this grammar, isn't it? Further, the parser should be feed with a sentence and then the tree could be yielded, no?

Comment: @Bikash - Yes and No. You *can* use a parser generator (like yacc or bison) if you want to, or you can write your own recursive-descent parser (it's remarkably simple). If you use yacc or bison, you need to write actions that will actually build the tree. I don't think yacc/bison give you the tree by itself. They simply recognize the grammar.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to match the whole thing with a single regular expression isn't going to get you too far, since regular expressions output at most a list of matching substring positions, nothing tree-like.  You want a lexer or grammar which does something like this:

Divide the input into tokens - atomic pieces like '{', '|', and 'world', then process those tokens in order.  Start with an empty tree with a single root node.

Every time you find `{`, create and go to a child node.

Every time you find `|`, create and go to a sibling node.

Every time you find `}`, go up to the parent node.

Every time you find a word, put that word in the current leaf node.

Comment: How does that address the case `{{text} {text}}`? I think his string is kind of ambiguous ... all sibling nodes should perhaps be delimited with "|"

Comment: Yes, there are some confusing points in the example.  It looks like the `} {` between Hey and world and the `}|{` between earth and Goodbye cause sibling-like relationships at different depths in the tree.  I could only guess at why this is.  (Another problem I noted with my own algorithm: what if { is right after a word, like for 'globe'?)  So this isn't a complete solution, but "something like" it ought to be adaptable to solve this type of problem.

Answer (score 3):

if you want a quick hack:

- replace the { chars with [
- replace the } chars with ]
- replace the | chars with spaces
- hope you dont get input with spaces.

`read` it in so it comes up as nested arrays.

ps: I agree that a reg-ex can't do this.

pss: set * read-eval * to false (you don't want the input running it's self)

Comment: His example string actually includes a space in one of the segments.

Comment: @Rayne: That was edited in. The OP did not include space in any of the resulting leaf strings.

Comment: Oh. I was also considering this solution as well, up until I saw the space. Then I cried myself to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [amotoen](http://github.com/richard-lyman/amotoen) to build grammar and parse this:

```
(ns pegg.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:use
   (com.lithinos.amotoen
    core string-wrapper))
  (:use clojure.contrib.pprint))

(def input "{{Hello big|Hi|Hey} {world|earth}|{Goodbye|farewell} {planet|rock|globe{.|!}}}")

(def grammar
     {
      :Start :List
      :ws #"^[ \n\r\t]*"
      :Sep "|"
      :String #"^[A-Za-z !.]+"
      :Item '(| :String :List)
      :Items [:Item '(+ [:Sep :Item])]
      :List [:ws "{" '(* (| :Items :Item)) "}" :ws]
      })

(def parser (create-parser grammar))

(defn parse
  [^String input]
  (validate grammar)
  (pprint (parser (wrap-string input))))
```

Result:

```
pegg.core> (parse input)
{:List [{:ws ""} "{" ({:Item {:List [{:ws ""} "{" ({:Items [{:Item {:String "Hello big"}} ([{:Sep "|"} {:Item {:String "Hi"}}] [{:Sep "|"} {:Item {:String "Hey"}}])]}) "}" {:ws " "}]}} {:Items [{:Item {:List [{:ws ""} "{" ({:Items [{:Item {:String "world"}} ([{:Sep "|"} {:Item {:String "earth"}}])]}) "}" {:ws ""}]}} ([{:Sep "|"} {:Item {:List [{:ws ""} "{" ({:Items [{:Item {:String "Goodbye"}} ([{:Sep "|"} {:Item {:String "farewell"}}])]}) "}" {:ws " "}]}}])]} {:Item {:List [{:ws ""} "{" ({:Items [{:Item {:String "planet"}} ([{:Sep "|"} {:Item {:String "rock"}}] [{:Sep "|"} {:Item {:String "globe"}}])]} {:Item {:List [{:ws ""} "{" ({:Items [{:Item {:String "."}} ([{:Sep "|"} {:Item {:String "!"}}])]}) "}" {:ws ""}]}}) "}" {:ws ""}]}}) "}" {:ws ""}]}
```

P.S. This is one of my first peg grammar and it can be better. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar