# Java regex - match a set of square brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to construct a regex that will return true to a set of multiple square brackets, as long as they are opened and closed correctly.

For e.g.

```
[1][2][3] - true
[1][2][3][4][5] - true
[[1,2],[2]] - true
```

I got this one but am able to do it for only 3 : "\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]"

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Java regex does not support recursion. You may use a regex for a 1 or 2 nested levels, but then it becomes unwieldly.

Comment: Just use counter. Increment it when you found `[` decrement when you found `]`. If counter ever goes negative there is a problem. If counter at the end is different than `0` there is also a problem.

Comment: This post might have some useful information... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826395/parse-string-into-a-tree-structure

Comment: Proper answer is that it can't be done with regex in Java. To get idea of possible solution take a look at duplicate question.